# sinch messaging APi Recieving duplicate messages

Tags: android, sinch

I am using the [sinch.com](https://sinch.com)'s service for instant messaging but I recieve old messages anytime a user logs in or reinstall the app. 
actually those messages have already been retrieved from their servers..    according to their documentation the messages are persisted only when the user is not online and also the persist the message for maximum of **30** days after when it will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

the issue might be the way you have implemented the sinch api.  you can limit the IM retrieval only for certain  time  range. Can you share your code snippet  or explain a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

When you log out, our servers dont know that the messages have been delivered to that device. We keep messages for delivery for 30 days. AS a developer you will experience this more since you are wiping the install when you deploy.

If you just kill the app and launch it again you will see that its not delivered again.

Comment: this is not the case, i keep receiving the messages any time i login.... this has happened on several occassiopns